# Memory cleanup in functions with many return points

Tags: c

I often have functions which allocate memory for a bunch of variables. Each malloc call may fail, and checking for each return value causes my code to get too long. Here's an example:

```
int some_func(size_t len1, size_t len2, size_t len3)
{
       char *a;
       struct someStruct *p1;
       struct otherStruct *p2;

       /* Just to avoid values of 0 in malloc */
       if ((len1 == 0) || (len2 == 0) || (len3 == 0)) {
               printf("Must give positive parameters.");
               return -1;
       }

       a = malloc(len1);

       if (a == NULL) {
               printf("malloc failed.");
               return -1;
       }

       p1 = malloc(len2);

       if (p1 == NULL) {
               printf("malloc failed.");
               free(a);
               return -1;
       }

       p2 = malloc(len2);

       if (p2 == NULL) {
               printf("malloc failed.");
               free(a);
               free(p1);
               return -1;
       }

       /* ... do actually useful stuff ... */

       free(a);
       free(p1);
       free(p2);
       return 0;
}
```

Here, every single time I call malloc, I also need to add the if-statement and free every variable which was previously allocated. Keeping track of this eventually becomes tedious, and many lines of code get repeated (all the previous free() calls are repeated in the next malloc() error block).

I would think this is a common problem, so how do people usually deal with this?
The other solution I see is using a "goto" to some cleanup code that frees everything.
But this may lead to complications if some variables get freed before that, during normal execution.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why people use C++.

Comment: You are right - 'goto' is the common solution here. Check some great C apps (ffmpeg, git) for many examples.

Comment: @Mysticial how does C++ handle it?

Comment: @TobErnack [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Comment: If thinks malloc is tedious try using pthreads. Oh the pain that was. Life is too short for malloc and pthread mutexs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do it like something like this:

```
int some_func(size_t len1, size_t len2, size_t len3)
{
   int rCode=0;
   char *a = NULL;
   struct someStruct *p1 = NULL;
   struct otherStruct *p2 = NULL;

   /* Just to avoid values of 0 in malloc */
   if ((len1 == 0) || (len2 == 0) || (len3 == 0)) {
      printf("Must give positive parameters.");
      rCode=(-1);
      goto CLEANUP;
   }

   a = malloc(len1);
   if (a == NULL) {
      printf("malloc failed.");
      rCode=(-1);
      goto CLEANUP;
   }

   p1 = malloc(len2);
   if (p1 == NULL) {
      printf("malloc failed.");
      rCode=(-1);
      goto CLEANUP;
   }

   p2 = malloc(len2);
   if (p2 == NULL) {
      printf("malloc failed.");
      rCode=-1;
      goto CLEANUP;
   }

   /* ... do actually useful stuff ... */


CLEANUP:

   if(a)
      free(a);

   if(p1)
      free(p1);

   if(p2)
      free(p2);

   return(rCode);
}
```

But perhaps, more like this:

```
int some_func(size_t len1, size_t len2, size_t len3)
   {
   int                 rCode = 0;
   char               *a     = NULL;
   struct someStruct  *p1    = NULL;
   struct otherStruct *p2    = NULL;

   /* Just to avoid values of 0 in malloc */
   if((0 == len1) || (0 == len2) || (0 == len3)) 
      {
      printf("Must give positive parameters.");
      rCode=EINVAL;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   errno=0;
   a = malloc(len1);
   if(NULL == a) 
      {
      rCode=errno?errno:ENOMEM;
      printf("malloc failed.  errno:%d", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   errno=0;
   p1 = malloc(len2);
   if(NULL == p1) 
      {
      rCode=errno?errno:ENOMEM;
      printf("malloc failed.  errno:%d", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   errno=0;
   p2 = malloc(len2);
   if(NULL == p2) 
      {
      rCode=errno?errno:ENOMEM;
      printf("malloc failed.  errno:%d", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* ... do actually useful stuff ... */


CLEANUP:

   if(a)
      free(a);

   if(p1)
      free(p1);

   if(p2)
      free(p2);

   return(rCode);
   }
```

***BONUS*** [Mahonri's list of rules for writing maintainable code](http://www.mahonri.info/doc/MahonriListOfRulesForWritingMaintainableCCode.html)

Comment: I don't have a specific example in mind, but what if a value not being NULL is not enough to guarantee free() won't crash? Say, if it may have been freed before.

Comment: @TobErnack, If I understand correctly, free() is not called if the value is NULL.  Hence, there is no possibility of a crash in free().  NULL equates to 0, which equates to FALSE.  Hence, 'free(a)' is only called if 'a' is non-NULL.

Comment: I mean when the value is garbage. Say I already called free(a) previously (for some arbitrary reason) and then I call free(a) again. The second call will crash because the memory was already freed.

Comment: @TobErnack, It would be important, in that case, to set 'a' to NULL after calling 'free(a)'.  In my professional code, I have my own free function that sets 'a' to NULL before returning.  Something like: __int MyFree(void **ptr) {free(*ptr); *ptr=NULL;}__  It is called like this: __MyFree((void **)&a);__

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer. That's UB. Your `MyFree` must cast `ptr` back to its actual type (which it is ignorant of).

Comment: `free(NULL)` is perfectly safe and does nothing, per ANSI C, C89, C99, and C11. Something like `static void *myfree(void *const ptr) { free(ptr); return NULL; }` and `a=myfree(a);` is perfectly safe and well-defined behaviour, no need for casting. (Why should there be? `malloc()` returns a `void *`, after all, and has zero idea what type you cast it to, afterwards. Only function pointers are special.) Claim of UB is utterly wrong. Tob Ernack: if you manipulate pointers (possibly garbling them), keep the original pointer around for freeing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to allocate everything first, then handle it if anything failed:

```
int some_func(size_t len1, size_t len2, size_t len3)
{
    char *a;
    struct someStruct *p1;
    struct otherStruct *p2;
    int success = 1;

    /* Just to avoid values of 0 in malloc */
    if ((len1 == 0) || (len2 == 0) || (len3 == 0)) {
        printf("Must give positive parameters.");
        return -1;
    }

    a = malloc(len1);
    if (a == NULL)
        success = 0;

    p1 = malloc(len2);
    if (p1 == NULL)
        success = 0;

    p2 = malloc(len2);
    if (p2 == NULL)
        success = 0;

    if (success) {
        /* do something useful */
        return 0;
    }

    /* One or more allocs failed. Say so, clean up, exit. */

    printf("malloc() failed.\n");

    free(a);
    free(p1);
    free(p2);

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This seems reasonable, although I am curious whether there are cases when not returning as soon as possible could lead to other problems? (It probably doesn't apply in my case, because I don't have any strict memory requirements)

Comment: I don't see how. Either `malloc()` returns a valid pointer, or it returns `NULL`. An earlier failure should not affect later calls to `malloc()`.

Comment: Oh, did you want to just use the allocated stuff in place and then free before returning? I had thought the pointers should be returned to the caller in some way. Well, the rewrite for that should be clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

First advice is you should try to redesign your code with less number of failure points.

In some cases this may be impossible. In this case I like this pattern:

```
char *a = NULL;
struct someStruct *p1 = NULL;
struct otherStruct *p2 = NULL;
int success = TRUE;

if (success)
{
    a = malloc(len1);
    if (a == NULL)
        success = FALSE;
}

if (success)
{
    p1 = malloc(len2);
    if (p1 == NULL)
        success = FALSE;
}

if (success)
{
    p2 = malloc(len2);
    if (p2 == NULL)
        success = FALSE;
}

if (success)
{
    /* Do something useful and DO NOT RETURN. */
}

if (a != NULL)
   free(a);
if (p1 != NULL)
   free(a);
if (p2 != NULL)
   free(a);
```

This pattern does have some overhead, but at least adding one more resource does not require to change all unrelated lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I commonly handle multiple allocations. I prefer to return zero for no error, and nonzero errno otherwise (EINVAL if one of the parameters is zero, ENOMEM if out of memory, in this case).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int do_something(const size_t n1, const size_t n2, const size_t n3)
{
    char *a;
    struct somestruct *b;
    struct otherstruct *c;

    if (n1 == 0 || n2 == 0 || n3 == 0)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    a = malloc(n1);             /* n1 chars */
    b = malloc(n2 * sizeof *b); /* n2 somestructs */
    c = malloc(n3 * sizeof *c); /* n3 otherstructs */
    if (a == NULL || b == NULL || c == NULL) {
        free(c);
        free(b);
        free(a);
        return errno = ENOMEM;
    }

    /* ... use a, b, c ... */

    /* If you free one of the pointers,
       for example conditionally,
       just set the pointer to NULL then too:
    */
    if (n1 == 7) {
       free(b);
       b = NULL;
    }

    /* Discard dynamically allocated memory
       that has not yet been deallocated.
    */
    free(c);
    free(b);
    free(a);

    /* Return success. */
    return 0;
}
```

Points to note:

- `sizeof` is a keyword, not a function. The thing it applies to is *not referenced*. Above, it is applied to `*a`, `*b`, and `*c`, respectively. This is a common, safe, method to refer to the size of the element the pointer `a`, `b`, or `c` points to, even when the pointer itself is undefined.

  Simply put, when you use `sizeof *a`, only the *type* pointer `a` points to, is examined: `a` is *never* dereferenced. So, it is perfectly safe even when `a` is NULL or undefined. This is not UB (undefined behaviour).
- `sizeof (char) == 1` according to the C standards. (`sizeof (signed char) == 1` and `sizeof (unsigned char) == 1`, too.)
- `free(NULL)` is safe, and has no effect. This is dictated in the C standards. (For example, in [ANSI C](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt), you can find it in section 4.10.3.2.)
- You can do all your allocations at once, then check if any of them failed, and if so, free all of them. This is because `malloc()` returns either a valid pointer, or NULL; never garbage.

  (Many operating systems provide a facility called [memory overcommit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment), where more virtual memory is defined than there is actual physical RAM available. This means that in extreme cases, a process may get killed because the OS kernel cannot provide the necessary physical RAM to actually access some memory the process has already allocated. You should not worry about this, because this is a catastrophic situation to the user anyway, and it's up to the system administrator (or OS vendor) to make sure this happens as rarely as possible. There is very little an application can do to avoid this, anyway -- aside from being reasonably frugal with memory use in the first place. In all cases I've seen defensive techniques used, they've only caused harm. I only mentioned this to be thorough.)
- The `return errno = EFOOBAR;` may look slightly odd, but in C, it's perfectly okay: the simple assignment evaluates to its value, `(errno = EFOOBAR) == EFOOBAR`. I use this extensively in library code for error conditions, so that the user code can do

  ```
  if (do_something(count1, count2, count3)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "do_something failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ```

  In C, a zero is False, and any nonzero value is True; therefore the body of the if statement is only executed if the function returns nonzero, i.e. an error code.

  (Zero `errno` has no predefined constant in the standards, but it does mean "no error" in all C library implementations I know of. Similarly, all C libraries define `NULL` as `(void *)0`. This is not dictated by any C standard as far as I know, but practice trumps paper.)

  If you dislike this, feel free to remove the `errno =` parts from the above code. The only difference is then that the caller needs to use a temporary variable to remember the result value, if they want to display a reasonable error message.

  Refer to your C library and/or OS vendor documentation for `errno` codes. For POSIXy code (Linux, Mac, BSDs, etc.) I use [man 3 errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).
- If you are unsure whether a pointer will get allocated, assign NULL to it at the declaration: `char *a = NULL;`. You can then safely call `free(a);` whether `a` was allocated or not.
- If you can free pointers early, do so; just set them to NULL afterwards, so that you do not need to worry about whether you have released them yet or not.
- I prefer to release pointers in the reverse order I allocate them. This is not necessary, and with most C library implementations, does not matter *at all*. There is no impact on performance. In some cases it may reduce fragmentation, so that more unused memory can be returned to the OS earlier, but even that is rare.

  I do this because it helps me perceive and think about the code structure better; it is more symmetric this way, and pleases me.  I am not saying you should do the same, but you might find a benefit of trying to assume structural styles that help you write better code. I use this one only because it helps me.

Questions?